# Activity.recreate() causing Butterknife binding to fail - Views are becoming null

Tags: android, butterknife

So far have no issues with ButterKnife (v8.8.1). Gradle settings, binding variables and unbinding and moving between activities all is well. But now `Activity.recreate()` in one of the activities causing the activity to crash mentioning the views are now null.

Initially, I was missing following line in project-level gradle but never faced an issue; Tried adding it but after adding and syncing the problem is not resolved yet.

```
dependencies(){
    //For Butterknife
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
}
```

Activity high-level code

```
Activity {
  private Activity mThisActivity;
  @BindView(R.id.txt) TextView view1;

onCreate() {
        mThisActivity = this;
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this);
        view1.setText("Hello world!");
}

onDestroy() {
//
       unbinder.unbind();
}

sometMethod() {
    mThisActivity.recreate();  //After calling this line above view1 becoming null and setText producing NPE.
}
}
```

Comment: where's `setContentView`?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti if you notice, I mentioned the code high-level only mentioned the useful lines to understand and debug the issue. Also please note, the activity was working fine with butterknife IF the recreate line is ommitted.

Answer (score 0):

Check out if you are not missing Maven Central repository in your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
   mavenCentral()    
}
```

Comment: Is it different from below two repos? Asking because until I added the recreate line, the application was working seamlessly with butterknife:                                 
           maven() {url "https://jitpack.io"}
        maven() {url "https://maven.google.com"}